# ArcGIS JavaScript API and Wordpress: How would you populate text box outside map with info from inside the map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, embeddable-web-maps

So, using WordPress, my organization is creating a survey/questionnaire. Within this multi-stage questionnaire, they want an address box with a map underneath. They want the user to be able to type in the address of concern (mind you, this would be an html text box *outside* the embedded map) and have it show on the map and also be able to click on a parcel on the map and have the address box auto-populate. Can ArcGIS JavaScript API be used within items outside of the embedded map? and can you then make the map and those external pieces work together? How would you go about doing this or something similar?

I am brand-new to the JavaScript API for ArcGIS, and I'm only to the point where I can embed a map, and call upon layers, add widgets. I don't have the slightest clue how to do what I described yet, any help or alternative ideas?